# Where does the function map come from?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

All. Forgive me I am not good in the AngularJS and AugularJS-UI.

Currently, I am trying to get the typeahead directive work in my page.

Here is the code. Please review it.

**Html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in DetailsOfCurRecipe">
                <td><div id="scrollable-dropdown-menu"><input name="DrugDetailName" ng-model="item.ProductName" typeahead="address for address in getDrugDetails($viewValue)" /></div><input type="hidden" name="DrugDetailID" value="{{item.ID}}" /><input type="hidden" name="DrugFileID" value="{{item.DrugFileID}}" /></td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.getDrugDetails = function (val) {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:6249/api/DrugDetails/all', {}).then(function (response) {
            return response.data.map(function (item) {
                return item.ProductName;
            });
        });
    };
```

I just want to know Where does the `response.data.map` function come from ? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: No angular, Javascript [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: It's ok with angular too, because `response.data` is an angular object.

Comment: @SimoEndre no, `response.data` is the body response of the request, in OP case it's an Array, nothing to do with Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from [the Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It is part of [standard core JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19).

Answer (score 1):

`response.data` is the object coming from the angular `http` service, and the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a native Javascript function. Here is the definition for `map` function:

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.